# How can I use a positional parameter as a suffix when making a directory?

Tags: string, bash, variables, string-concatenation

I'm writing a small bash script and I'm trying to create a directory by this:

`mkdir ~/deploy.$1`

I would think it should produce deploy.scriptFoo or what ever the valuable of $1 is.

It's only producing "deploy." and leaving off the $1 variable.  I have tested the $1 variable in the output and I am positive it is being passed into the script.  Any ideas?

Comment: Forgive a very basic question, but are you calling the script with `scriptFoo` as its first argument:  `./myscript scriptFoo` ?  What happens if you change the line to `echo mkdir ~/deploy.$1` ?

Comment: It works for me. Show the rest of the script and how you're calling it plus the output of the `echo` that Adam Liss suggests.

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

The $1 position parameter is the first argument to your script, not the name of the script itself.

#### The Solution

If you want the script name, use $0. For example, given this sample script stored in /tmp/param_test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "/tmp/deploy.$(basename "$0" .sh)"
ls -d /tmp/deploy*
```

the script ignores any arguments, but correctly returns the following output:

> /tmp/deploy.param_test

If you want to vary the name, then you have to use a positional parameter in your script *and* call the script with an argument. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "/tmp/deploy.$1"
ls -d /tmp/deploy*
```

On the command line, you pass the argument to your script. For example:

```
$ bash /tmp/param_test.sh foo
/tmp/deploy.foo
```

#### See Also

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters